# ¿Por que al mandar los datos de inputs con el mismo name a la variable $_POST['']; no crea un arreglo, sino solo guarda un dato?

Tags: php

El motivo por el cual necesito usar el mismo `name` para cada una de los inputs es porque dichos inputs son generados por el usuario, es decir, no hay un numero fijo, puden ser, 2, 3, 4, etc. Por ello cuando estos `<inputs>` son creados llevan el mismo `name`. Segun leí, en sí las variables `$_POST[""];` y `$_GET[""];` son arreglos. Sin enbargo cuando `print_r()` se ejecuta, solo muestra un solo indice en el arreglo. ¿Como puedo hacerle para guardar los datos de cada input dentro de `$_POST[""];`?

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','capacitacion');

    $pregunta = $_POST['pregunta'];
    $opciones = $_POST['opciones'];

    print_r($opciones);
?>
```

Comment: Eso ocurre porque un array no puede tener dos veces el mismo valor, prevaleciendo el último. Puedes poner el name así para que te lo guarde como array: `<input name="opciones[]"  .... />` ahí tendrás en `$_POST['opciones']` una lista de cada valor que se introdujo en los inputs con ese `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando un formulario es enviado sus valores son serializados y cuando intentas recuperarlos vía `$_GET` o `$_POST` PHP crea un array con los datos del formulario.

Si en el formulario hay varias etiquetas con el mismo `name`, únicamente prevalecerá el último.

Para indicar que en ese `name` irán varios posibles valores de distintos inputs tienes que poner esto después del identificador `[]`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" name="options[]" />
<input type="text" name="options[]" />
```

Cuando el formulario se envíe y lo recuperes en el servidor:

```
$mOptions=$_POST['options'];
var_dump($mOptions);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) { 
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "b"
}
```

Ya puedes trabajar `$mOptions` para mostrarlo separado por comas o lo que quieras.