# input agregado con JS no aparece en "POST"

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy trabajando con un formulario en el cual elegis cierto objeto y js agrega los atributos que debes completar dependiendo del tipo de objeto para subirlo a la base de datos usando la funcion de innerHTML.
El problema es que luego cuando lo mando por POST, lo que agregamos con el innerHTML no aparece.
Alguna idea de como resolverlo?

HTML:

```html
<form id="product_form" method="POST">
        <button name="save">Save</button>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><hr></td></tr></table></center>
    <center> <?php echo $alert?></center>
    <center><table class="product_table">
    <tr>
        <td width="20%"><label for="sku">SKU</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sku" class="sku"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="price">Price</label></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="price" class="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td id="selectionError"></td>
    </tr>
        <td>Type Switcher</td>
        <td><select name="productType" id="productType">
            <option value="">Select the product type</option>
            <option value="DVD">DVD</option>
            <option value="Book">Book</option>
            <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table><br>
<table class="product_table" id="type">
</table>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</form>
```

JS:

```js
const productType = document.getElementById('productType');
const type = document.getElementById('type');
const selectionError = document.getElementById('selectionError');


productType.addEventListener('change',change)

function change(){
    if(productType.value == ""){
        selectionError.innerHTML = "<p style='color:red;text-align:center;'>Please select a product Type</p>";
        type.innerHTML = "";
    }else{
        selectionError.innerHTML = "";
        if(productType.value == "DVD"){
            type.innerHTML = `
            <tr><td width="20%">Size (in MB)</td><td><input type="number" name="size" id="size" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>*Please provide the DVD size in MB</td></tr>
            `
        }else if(productType.value == "Book"){
            type.innerHTML = `
            <tr><td width="20%">Weight (KG)</td><td><input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>*Please provide the Book's weight in KG</td></tr>
            `
        }else if(productType.value == "Furniture"){
            type.innerHTML = `
            <tr><td width="20%">Height </td><td><input type="number" name="height" id="height" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td width="20%">Width </td><td><input type="number" name="width" id="width" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td width="20%">Length </td><td><input type="number" name="length" id="length" required></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td>*Please provide the Dimensions in CM</td></tr>
            `
        }
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$sku = $_POST['sku'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$type = $_POST['productType'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$size =  $_POST['size'];
$weight = $_POST['weight']; 
$height = $_POST['height'];
$width =  $_POST['width'];
$length =  $_POST['length'];

$alert = $con->addProduct($sku,$name,$price,$type,$size,$weight,$height,$width,$length) . " Size: $size, Weight: $weight, Height: $height, Width: $width, Length: $length";
```

}

PRINT_R in PHP:
Array ( [save] => [sku] => eqweqweq [name] => adwadwad [price] => 12321 [productType] => Book )

Como se ve en el codigo, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que si el usuario selecciona cierto "Tipo" como por ejemplo "DVD", JS le muestra el atributo "Size" para que se complete. Luego deberia enviarse por POST pero no puedo hacer que funcione.

Muchas gracias por su tiempo!!

Comment: Al usar varios campos con el mismo nombre, se enviará solo uno, generalmente el último. Te recomiendo leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/331137/54039), en la respuesta se indica cómo crear campos como arreglos.

Comment: Hola @Triby ! Muchas gracias por tu comentario! Creo que no tengo ningun campo repetido.. Te referis a alguno en particular que no este viendo?

Saludos!

Comment: Una pregunta, @Kuai... ¿el `change` se ejecuta correctamente y te aparecen los nuevos `input` que deseas?

Comment: Hola @VFG te referis a si me aparecen los campos con el innerHTML de js? Si, el problema es cuando apreto en SEND

Comment: Como vi tabla, pensé que estabas agregando más de un producto, pero ya vi que remplazas el contenido de la tabla dependiendo de la opción seleccionada. Entonces, los campos no siempre están presentes y debes asegurarte de obtener un valor adecuado. Puedes usar [operador ternario](https://www.neoguias.com/if-abreviado-en-php-el-operador-ternario/). Ejemplo: `$weight = (isset($_POST['weight'])) ? $_POST['weight'] : '';`

Answer (score 0):

Kuai, te paso el ejemplo más similar a tu código posible, que funciona sin problemas. He tenido varias confusiones respecto a tu código porque se cierran y abren etiquetas que no sé dónde empezaban o terminaban, etc. Y también un lío con las asignaciones de contenido a `type.innerHTML`, pero en cualquier caso te paso el código de página completa php para que pruebes que todo va correctamente.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <?php
          if(isset($_POST['save'])){
            print_r($_POST);
           } else {
        ?>        
        
        <form id="product_form" method="POST">
                <button name="save">Save</button>
            
            <center> <?php echo $alert?></center>
            <center>
                <table class="product_table">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%"><label for="sku">SKU</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="sku" class="sku"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" class="name"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="price">Price</label></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="price" class="price"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td><td id="selectionError"></td>
                    </tr>
                        <td>Type Switcher</td>
                        <td><select name="productType" id="productType">
                            <option value="">Select the product type</option>
                            <option value="DVD">DVD</option>
                            <option value="Book">Book</option>
                            <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
            <table class="product_table" id="type">
            </table>
            
            <script>
                const productType = document.getElementById('productType');
                const type = document.getElementById('type');
                const selectionError = document.getElementById('selectionError');                   
                
                productType.addEventListener('change',change);
                
                function change(){
                    if(productType.value == ""){
                        selectionError.innerHTML = "<p style='color:red;text-align:center;'>Please select a product Type</p>";
                        type.innerHTML = "";
                    }else{
                        selectionError.innerHTML = "";
                        if(productType.value == "DVD"){
                            type.innerHTML = "<tr><td width=\"20%\">Size (in MB)</td><td><input type=\"number\" name=\"size\" id=\"size\" required></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>*Please provide the DVD size in MB</td></tr>";
                        }else if(productType.value == "Book"){
                            type.innerHTML = "<tr><td width=\"20%\">Weight (KG)</td><td><input type=\"number\" name=\"weight\" id=\"weight\" required></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>*Please provide the Book s weight in KG</td></tr>";
                        }else if(productType.value == "Furniture"){
                            type.innerHTML = "<tr><td width=\"20%\">Height </td><td><input type=\"number\" name=\"height\" id=\"height\" required></td></tr><tr><td width=\"20%\">Width </td><td><input type=\"number\" name=\"width\" id=\"width\" required></td></tr><tr><td width=\"20%\">Length </td><td><input type=\"number\" name=\"length\" id=\"length\" required></td></tr><tr><td></td><td>*Please provide the Dimensions in CM</td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            </script>
        </form>
        
        <?php
           }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta ya te la había dado @Triby, el error que obtienes es porque algunos apartados son dinámicos, estos se generan dependiendo la opción seleccionada, en php tu declaras las variables que recibirán los datos enviados del formulario **"No llegaran todos los datos"**, por ende en PHP tienes que usar operadores ternarios, esto para dar un valor a la variable que no esta recibiendo nada y evitar el error, ejemplo:

```html
<form id="product_form" method="POST" action="process.php">
  <table class="product_table">
    <tr>
      <td width="20%"><label for="sku">SKU</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="sku" class="sku"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="name" class="name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="price">Price</label></td>
      <td><input type="number" name="price" class="price"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="selectionError"></td>
    </tr>
    <td>Type Switcher</td>
    <td>
      <select name="productType" id="productType">
        <option value="">Select the product type</option>
        <option value="DVD">DVD</option>
        <option value="Book">Book</option>
        <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <table class="product_table" id="type">

    </table>
    <button name="save">Save</button>
  </table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```js
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    $sku = $_POST['sku'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $type = $_POST['productType'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $size =  (isset($_POST['size'])) ? $_POST['size'] : '';
    $weight = (isset($_POST['weight'])) ? $_POST['weight'] : ''; 
    $height = (isset($_POST['height'])) ? $_POST['height'] : '';
    $width =  (isset($_POST['width'])) ? $_POST['width'] : '';
    $length = (isset($_POST['length'])) ? $_POST['length'] : '';
    
    //$alert = $con->addProduct($sku,$name,$price,$type,$size,$weight,$height,$width,$length) . " Size: $size, Weight: $weight, Height: $height, Width: $width, Length: $length";
    echo $sku.'-'.$size.'-'.$weight.'-'.$width.'-'.$length;
}
?>
```